# How I can rotate an image DICOM using Cornerstone in axis X and Z?

Tags: javascript, rotation, cornerstonejs

I want to rotate an image dicom using Cornerstone with Rotate Tool about axis X and Z but I saw that only allow rotate about axis Y.

Anyone known how I could rotate an image dicom about all axis using other library + Cornerstone library?

Thanks.

I tried this code:

```
// Importar las bibliotecas necesarias
import cornerstone from 'cornerstone-core';
import * as cornerstoneTools from 'cornerstone-tools';

// Habilitar el visor Cornerstone.js
cornerstone.enable(document.getElementById('viewer'));

// Cargar una imagen DICOM utilizando Cornerstone.js
const imageId = 'dicomImageId';
cornerstone.loadImage(imageId).then(image => {
  // Renderizar la imagen en el visor
  cornerstone.displayImage(document.getElementById('viewer'), image);

  // Habilitar la herramienta de rotación
  const rotateTool = cornerstoneTools.RotateTool;
  cornerstoneTools.addTool(rotateTool);
  cornerstoneTools.setToolActive('Rotate', { mouseButtonMask: 1 });

  // Función de controlador para la rotación
  function handleRotation(e) {
    const eventData = e.detail;
    const viewport = cornerstone.getViewport(e.currentTarget);
    const rotationAngle = eventData.rotation;
    const rotationRadians = cornerstoneTools.degreesToRadians(rotationAngle);
    const centerPoint = {
      x: eventData.currentPoints.image.x,
      y: eventData.currentPoints.image.y
    };
    cornerstoneTools.rotate(viewport, rotationRadians, centerPoint);
    cornerstone.setViewport(e.currentTarget, viewport);
  }

  // Agregar el controlador de eventos para la rotación
  document.getElementById('viewer').addEventListener('cornerstonetoolsmousemove', handleRotation);
});
```

And my expecting is that I can rotate an image dicom in all axis